# Move Windows default installation path by using shortcut, stupid or smart?

Tags: path, installation, default

I'm running low on memory on my C:\ but I have plenty on D:\

My goal is to make it so all programs installs to D:/Programs even those dumb programs where you don't get an option to choose where they will be installed.

I have been looking into different ways to move the default installation path & register edits & things, but most of them are kind of dangerous, really annoying to do &/or might bring unexpected side effects; like the programs cant be found & such.

But then I found a suggestion to use the windows cmd (commandpromts) mklink command to basically make a shortcut from C:\Programs to D:\Programs

But I'm thinking: *What happens if I simply Drag & drop the C:\Programs to D:\ then right click on it & chooses make shortcut & move that shortcut back to C:/*

**Is this a really stupid or smart solution?** (I'm leaning to dumb, because it's just too simple, but I don't know why it would be dumb?)

& does anyone knows what can go wrong with this solution?

I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why this would be stupid, a shortcut done in windows is apparently a file that points to the target & not all programs use it correctly, while using cmd to make a symbolic link is "registered to the hard drive" & it should work better.

Quote from [this page](https://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/):

"**Shortcuts, symbolic links, hard links & junctions?!**

A **shortcut** is a file that points to another file. It is an antiquated pointing system from the Windows 95 era that many programs do not recognise. Shortcuts do not only use up space on the hard drive, but they also break and linger behind after the deletion, renaming or moving of the target.

A **symbolic link** is similar to a shortcut, but instead of being saved as a file it is registered to the hard drive partition. It does not use any disk space, and all programs recognise both the link and the target. A symbolic link can point to any file or folder either locally on the computer or over a network using an SMB path.

A file **hard link** is a little different and can not be used over multiple partitions meaning you can not have a link on drive C: pointing to a file on drive D:. A file hard link points to and duplicates a target as a mirrored copy, but the duplicate does not use any additional space on the hard drive partition. So two hard links that mirror a 1 GB file would in total only use 1 GB on the partition rather than 3 GB. Importantly if either the hard links or the target were to delete, the other links retain the data. Changes to the content of either the target or the links automatically propagate to all other items.

A **junction** behaves like a hard link for directories, but unlike file hard links you can create junctions that span multiple partitions. Again a directory junction and its content are stored on the hard drive partition, but they do not use any additional space. Any changes to the content within either the target or the links will automatically propagate except where the target directory is deleted or renamed. In that case, all links that point to the target will break and linger on the partition."

Comment: DAMN! Windows have (obviously) put in protection against moving or renaming that folder. But I can't make a symbolic link from there while the folder is still there because the link can't have the same name as an existing folder. Anyone knows a "hack" around this problem?

Comment: Basically NO, not from inside Windows because a LOT of windows systems use those folders, including Explorer.exe which is windows user interface... I think this is my best bet, but ist's freaking annoying to do: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1557e84f-591a-46bb-86c4-3b38af2003b0/can-i-replace-the-program-files-folder-with-a-symbolic-link-to-another-drive?forum=w7itprogeneral